# How do I avoid a large z3 expression from being converted into an ellipsis in python?

Tags: python, eval, z3, z3py

I have a big z3 BitVec expression in a string format. To convert it into an expression of BitVec format, I use '*eval()*'. But, the expression turns into an ellipsis. How do I avoid this?

```
from z3 import *


a0=BitVec('a0',1)
a1=BitVec('a1',1)
c0=BitVec('c0',1)
c1=BitVec('c1',1)

b=BitVec('b',1)


d=BitVec('d',1)
f=BitVec('f',1)
g=BitVec('g',1)
e=BitVec('e',1)
h=BitVec('h',1)
a=BitVec('a',1)
c=BitVec('c',1)


exp = '(a&b&c)|(c&d&e&f&g)|(a1&a0&c1&c0)|(g&h)|f|(a&b&c)|(c&d&e&f&g)|(a1&a0&c1&c0)|(g&h)|(a&b&c)|(c&d&e&f&g)|(a1&a0&c1&c0)|(g&h)|f|(a&b&c)|(c&d&e&f&g)|(a1&a0&c1&c0)|(g&h)|(a&b&c)|(c&d&e&f&g)|(a1&a0&c1&c0)|(g&h)|f|(a&b&c)|(c&d&e&f&g)|(a1&a0&c1&c0)|(g&h)|(a&b&c)|(c&d&e&f&g)|(a1&a0&c1&c0)|(g&h)|f|(a&b&c)|(c&d&e&f&g)|(a1&a0&c1&c0)|(g&h)|(a&b&c)|(c&d&e&f&g)|(a1&a0&c1&c0)|(g&h)|f|(a&b&c)|(c&d&e&f&g)|(a1&a0&c1&c0)|(g&h)|(a&b&c)|(c&d&e&f&g)|(a1&a0&c1&c0)|(g&h)|f|(a&b&c)|(c&d&e&f&g)|(a1&a0&c1&c0)|(g&h)|(a&b&c)|(c&d&e&f&g)|(a1&a0&c1&c0)|(g&h)|f|(a&b&c)|(c&d&e&f&g)|(a1&a0&c1&c0)|(g&h)|(a&b&c)|(c&d&e&f&g)|(a1&a0&c1&c0)|(g&h)|f|(a&b&c)|(c&d&e&f&g)|(a1&a0&c1&c0)|(g&h)|(a&b&c)|(c&d&e&f&g)|(a1&a0&c1&c0)|(g&h)|f|(a&b&c)|(c&d&e&f&g)|(a1&a0&c1&c0)|(g&h)|(a&b&c)|(c&d&e&f&g)|(a1&a0&c1&c0)|(g&h)|f|(a&b&c)|(c&d&e&f&g)|(a1&a0&c1&c0)|(g&h)|(a&b&c)|(c&d&e&f&g)|(a1&a0&c1&c0)|(g&h)|f|(a&b&c)|(c&d&e&f&g)|(a1&a0&c1&c0)|(g&h)|(a&b&c)|(c&d&e&f&g)|(a1&a0&c1&c0)|(g&h)|f|(a&b&c)|(c&d&e&f&g)|(a1&a0&c1&c0)|(g&h)'

print(eval(exp))
```

output ::
... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |...

Answer (score 1):

Ellipses are controlled by pretty-printer settings in z3. You can add the following line at the top of your program, after the `import` statement:

```py
set_option(max_args=100000000, max_lines=10000000, max_depth=100000000, max_visited=10000000)
```

This will *usually* work for small enough problems. The issue is that the pretty-printer uses quite an inefficient algorithm to do so, and if you try the above in your example, you'll see that z3 is taking almost forever to print your expression; so it doesn't really work for your problem.

The other alternative is to print the s-expression that corresponds to your expression, instead of printing it in the more python-like format. To do so, change your final line to:

```py
print(eval(exp).sexpr())
```

You'll find that z3 quickly prints the output in this case, though the output is perhaps less "pretty" than what you might've expected. (In particular, it uses fully-parenthesized prefix notation; instead of the more familiar infix notation with reduced parenthesis.) In my opinion, however, it's quite readable, and probably the right thing to do here.

Comment: I want to process the expression further, converting eval(exp) into a string. But the string also turns into an ellipsis

Comment: Are you saying `s = eval(expr).sexpr()` results in `s` being ellipsis? I just tested and it comes out just fine. Please post the code that exhibits the problem.